# How to add event listeners to multiple elements with the same class and then only change CSS for specific other element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I basically want to make it possible to show and hide multiple blocks of text, completely separate to one another. So that when one of the buttons is pressed, the corresponding quote directly below it becomes visible (display: block), but *only* that quote.

This is what I have so far, but I have now ran in to a wall:

JS:

```
<script> 
    let btn = document.querySelectorAll('btn');
    let quote = document.querySelectorAll('quote');
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (quote.style.display == "block") {
            quote.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            quote.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>

<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>

<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>
```

Comment: Do you accept jQuery solutions? or plain javascript only?

Comment: Personally, I'd tend to put each `<button>` + `<p>` pair into its own `<div>` and do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcf0jn7d/

Answer (score 2):

You have do declare an event listener for every btn in a loop and declare the quote inside the listener. I changed the display check for the case that at the beginning there is no display style on the quote. You also forgot a dot in 'let btn'...

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        let quote = this.nextElementSibling;
        console.log('quote: ', quote);
        if (quote.style.display == "none") {
            quote.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            quote.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>

<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>

<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>
```

Comment: If this is the answer that helped you mark it as accepted...

Comment: Yeah this worked really well, just as i wanted. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @Ben To accept an answer you have to click an the check mark like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery i made this:

With `$(this)` the button you clicked on, and `.next()` giving the next element.

you can find the next element (i added a check to make sure the next element has the class quote before running) and apply your styling

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).next().hasClass('quote')) {
    $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>

<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>

<button class="btn">Click here to see the quote</button>
<p class="quote">blah blah blah</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to select class, it should be `querSelectorAll('.btn')` and `querSelectorAll('.quote')` (begin with a `.`).

Secondly, with `querSelectorAll`, your `btn` and `quote` variable will be lists of nodes (you should name it `btns` and `quotes` btw) so you won't be able to add event listener to it. What you should do is iterate throw your list and add event listener for each item:

```
let btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
btns.map(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (btn, idx) => handleBtnClick(btn, idx));
```

Then in `handleBtnClick`, you should select the div with corresponding `idx` and make it visible, while the others div invisible:

```
const handleBtnClick = (btn, idx) => {
    let quotes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.quote')];
    quotes.map( (quote, quotedIdx) => {
       if (quoteIdx === idx) {
          quote.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
          quote.style.display = 'none';
       }
    }
```

This code is no optimizied, please refacto as you please